# Android <-> php Unexpected response code 302

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am using Volley to connect my Android project and php.
I get uri of images from gallery (2 or more images), and put into ArrayList or JSON.
(When I tried with ArrayList, error code 302 was happen, then I changed to JSON, but same error is happened)
Then I send the ArrayList or JSON by using StringRequest as usually with Volley, but BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 302 for 
is happen

this is my code for incoding to Base64 of uri of images and putting ArrayList

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    encodedImageArrayList.add(encoded);
```

and this is sending to php

```
    map.put("images" , image.toString());
```

When I try to send only one image, it works, but when I try sending 2 or more images, the error is happen.

Comment: If it is `HTTP 302`, that is not an error code, just a status code, and one of the headers should include a `Location` that it wants to redirect to. Inspect that.

Comment: So get the data at php, I use code

$Images = $_POST["images"];

This is wrong way to get ARrayList from Android to PHP?